# syntax error: unexpected "echo " in PHP

Tags: php

there is unexpected echo on `$_SESSION['correctAnswer'] == echo $jawaban[$i]; ? " correct" : " incorrect";` line. please help

this is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $soal = $_SESSION['soal'];
    $no = $_SESSION['no'];
    if(isset($_POST['next'])){
        $_SESSION['jawab'][] = $_POST['option'];
        if($_POST['option'] == $soal[$no-2]['kunci']){
            $_SESSION['correctAnswer'] = $soal[$no-2]['kunci']; // add sthing like this
        }
    }
    if(isset($soal[$no-1])){ 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Latihan Soal</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="index.php">Kembali ke soal 1</a>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <p>
        <?php
            echo $no.". "; $_SESSION['no']++; 
            echo $soal[$no-1]['soal']; 
            $jawaban = $_SESSION['option'][$no-1]; 
            shuffle($jawaban); 
        ?>
         </p>
        <?php
            for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        ?>
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $jawaban[$i]; ?>" required/> <?php echo $jawaban[$i]; ?></br>
        <?php
         $_SESSION['correctAnswer'] == echo $jawaban[$i]; ? " correct" : " incorrect";    
            }
         ?>

        <input type="submit" name="next" value="next">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }else{
        header("location:result.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: why u are using echo there ?

Comment: You want to do this: `echo $_SESSION['correctAnswer'] == $jawaban[$i] ? " correct" : " incorrect";`

Comment: Should be `echo $_SESSION['correctAnswer'] ==  $jawaban[$i] ? " correct" : " incorrect";`

Comment: but then there is an error Undefined index: correctAnswer in C:\xampp\htdocs\aa\test.php on line 35

Comment: so what the code will be? i will make if i choose wrong radio button answer, then there is 'incorrect' in side. and if i choose right radio button answer then there is 'correct' in side.

Answer (score 5):

There's a `syntax error` in your ternary operator:

```
$_SESSION['correctAnswer'] == echo $jawaban[$i]; ? " correct" : " incorrect";
```

You should put echo before the ternary operator like this

```
echo $_SESSION['correctAnswer'] == $jawaban[$i] ? " correct" : " incorrect";
```

Comment: should remove the ";" after `$jawaban[$i];` too

Comment: Thanks @olibiaz - I didn't spot that, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
$_SESSION['correctAnswer'] == echo $jawaban[$i]; ? " correct" : " incorrect";
```

with

```
echo (($_SESSION['correctAnswer'] == $jawaban[$i]) ? " correct" : " incorrect");
```

Answer (score 0):

from horrible PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php):

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct)

So, it does not return anything.

And as it is a language construct - you got your error here. As if you have an unexpected 'if' or 'while' there. It doesn't make sense to PHP interpreter.

Remove that echo. as @splash58 said.